# Effect of humidity on static electricity

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, resource-recommendations, humidity

I am looking for a reference to a scientific paper or textbook that explains the effect of humidity on static electricity (triboelectric effect).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Google Scholar returns hundreds of publications that deal with the effect of humidity on static electricity in various conditions/materials.

Comment: I need something very general which I could not find on Google Scholar. Basically, I need a reference to a well known fact that static electricity effect is reduced with humidity.A simple graph showing a dependency of charge accumulation on humidity and/or theoretical explanation why humidity prevents/reduces charge accumulation will be great for me.

Comment: E.g.: http://www.asse.org/professionalsafety/docs/Alan%20McCartney%20Article.pdf?

Comment: The main mechanism is probably the adsorption of atmospheric water molecules on surfaces, a function that depends on humidity. This water film, which may even mobilize ions, makes surfaces more conductive (NOT the air!). Like anti-static spray, this allows charges to dissipate.

Comment: Since you are looking for some general references, you probably should look at books.google.com, rather than scholar.google.com, where research papers are usually treating particular case.

Comment: @Kyle: Minor point concerning retagging: I would say that the [tag:specific-reference] tag does not apply here cf. its [tag wiki](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-reference/info).

Comment: @Qmechanic I notice the reference-request tag seems to be gone. Should similar questions be flagged for closing? Or is there another tag?

Comment: @Kyle: The ref. req. tag was changed into the spec. ref. tag, cf. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5281/2451) meta post, where there is also more info.

Answer (score 1):

I was also curious about this topic when I read about it in class and wanted to know more about it. Unfortunately what I have found is that its pretty unlikely that there will be any general study on the effects of humidity on the triboelectric effect because for one, the effect is not very well known or for that matter relevant (though its effects on a nano scale do seem to be of some interest).

That being said Wikipedia does give the following statement on it:-

> Electrostatic discharge may not be evident in humid climates because
>   surface condensation normally prevents triboelectric charging, while
>   increased humidity increases the electrical conductivity of the air.

The above statement makes sense in light of the rest of the information about triboelectric effect. 
Though triboelectric effect is named after the word tribo (greek for rubbing) the two surfaces only need to come in contact for the effect to take place. The presence of water in humid climates creates a kind of barrier between them and prevents the charging process and in effect, stops the triboelectric effect from taking place.

Other than that, there are a number of specific studies that you can find in the following links:-
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304388688900216
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211285513001389